# Python3: change one character in a list of characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, character-replacement

I want to read a string from stdin and append this string to a list. Then I want to change one character at a time and append the new strings to the same list.

```
pat=sys.argv[1]
dummy1=list(str(pat))

myList=[]
list.append(pat)
c=0
for letter in dummy1:
    if dummy1[c]=="A":
        dummy1[c]=="C"
        depp=''.join(dummy1)
        myList.append(depp)
    c+=1
print(myList)
```

but when I try this, I only get a list containing my original string as often as I looped. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This ( in line 8 you should replace == with = ):

```
pat = "SALAM"   # Your Input Data

dummy1 = list(str(pat))
my_list = [pat]

c = 0
for letter in dummy1:

    if dummy1[c] == "A":

        dummy1[c] = "C"
        join_list = ''.join(dummy1)
        my_list.append(join_list)

    c += 1

last_data = my_list[len(my_list)-1]
print(last_data)
```

Comment: I know, comments are not meant for thanking, but I must have been screenblind. how stupid to use == (which would be checking if something is equal), when I want to assing a new "value" to dummy1 (with = ofc!)